# Let $T:X\to Y$ be continuous at $0.$ Then $\exists~k>0$ such that $\|Tx\|<k\|x\|.$

Tags: normed-spaces, proof-verification

Let $T:X\to Y,~(X,Y$ being Normed Linear Spaces$)$, be a linear transformation continuous at $0.$ Then $\exists~k>0$ such that $\|Tx\|<k\|x\|.$

My attempt:

$T$ is continuous at $0\implies$ for $\epsilon=1~\exists~\delta>0$ such that whenever $\|x\|<\delta,~\|Tx\|<1.$

Without loss of generality choose $x\ne0.$ Then $\|y\|=1$ where $y=\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}.$

By Archimedean Property,  $\exists~k\in\mathbb N$ such that $k\delta>1.$

Clearly $\left\|\dfrac{y}{k}\right\|=\dfrac{1}{k}<\delta$ whence $\left\|T\left(\dfrac{y}{k}\right)\right\|<1\implies\|Ty\|<k\implies\|Tx\|<k\|x\|.$

**Am I correct?**

Comment: What is $T$, exactly?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Properly edited.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: No. Why do we need that?

Comment: Sriti, your proof is correct! :) @Peter The result is true independent of the finite dimensionality of the normed linear spaces $X$ and $Y$. In fact, it's also easy to see that the reverse implication, that is, $T:X\to Y$ is a bounded linear operator $\implies$ $T$ is continuous at $0$, is valid.

Comment: @AmiteshDatta: Thanks so much.

Comment: @AmiteshDatta Wouldn't the statement be independent of the base point we choose?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I agree continuity at $0$ implies continuity at all points by linearity of the operator $T$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Amitesh Datta is a Mathematics Olympiad topper.

Comment: @AmiteshDatta: found it here: http://enrichmaths.sponsored.uwa.edu.au/__data/page/8069/OlympiadNews-Oct2009.pdf.

Comment: @Peter, Sriti I've deleted some of my comments above as they're off-topic and would likely be considered too chatty by the moderators. However, thank you both for your kind words; I appreciate them a lot! (Of course, I'm always happy and interested to discuss mathematics or anything else with both of you if you're interested; my contact details are on my profile page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that this has an answer I will just reply with a few comments.

Your proof is correct, and it is nice to to think topologically about what the proof is saying. The $y$ you construct is a dilation of $x$ to a suitably small neighborhood of 0. So it is essentially saying that everything is happening there. One corollary is that a continuous (bounded) linear operator is uniformly continuous. Furthermore it means that for a linear operator to be discontinuous it means it has to send very small (in norm) operators to arbitrarily large (in norm) elements of $Y$. From this perspective it is quite useful to show that the differentiation operator is unbounded on continuous function (or $L^p$).